# Structuring a SQL statement to display by depth

Tags: sql

```
"SELECT parent.name 
FROM categories AS node,
categories AS parent
WHERE node.left_node BETWEEN parent.left_node AND parent.right_node
AND node.name = '{$node_name}'
ORDER BY parent.right_node AND node.left_node"
```

The query above will display all the parent to the root of the node called. I only want to get the next parent, not all the way to the root, but only node above. for instance in the graphic below

[image: http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/7139/fruittree.gif]

If I call RED the statement will pull Fruit and Food, but instead I would like to structure the query to only pull the very next node to RED only which is "Fruit", don't need root node "Food".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exploit the fact that a any nodes left value is greater than that of it's parent (or that the right value is less than its parent), and use limit to just return what you want.

```
ORDER BY parent.left_node desc
LIMIT 1
```

this is mysql synax, i'm not sure what rdbms you are using.

It seems to me like there is probably a better way.

Comment: SELECT parent.name 
FROM categories AS node,
categories AS parent
WHERE node.left_node > parent.left_node 
AND node.name = '{$node_name}'
ORDER BY parent.left_node DESC
LIMIT 1"  It worked!

Comment: I have to say that in the  tree if I call yellow with the node.left_node > parent.left_node it will pull RED as its parent :( instead of FRUIT. but If I call RED it will pull up Fruit becuase the left_node of the node RED is just greater than the left of FRUIT. ?Let me try the other condition with the less than

Comment: Thank you paul, it did solved it. I can see SQL is very powerfull

Comment: if I want to food I would then have to limit it to 2? but then when I do that it display Fruit and Food when calling RED I just want to display FRuit now. that would be WHERE node.left_node > parent.left_node AND node.right_node < parent.right_node -1?